# scrapy create simple rule engine

Tags: python, scrapy, rule-engine

i m using scrapy to parse htmls.

```
def get_scripts(self, response):

    items = response.css('ul#top-menu').css('a::text').extract()
    if items:
        self.write_file(response.meta['item'],items)          
    else:
        items = response.css('ul.menu').css('a::text').extract()
        if items:
            self.write_file(response.meta['item'],items)

        else:
            items = response.css('ul.nav').css('a::text').extract()
            self.write_file(response.meta['item'],items)
```

Now i want to put all the logic inside a array. like

```
logicArr=['response.css('ul#top-menu').css('a::text').extract()','response.css('ul.menu').css('a::text').extract()','response.css('ul.nav').css('a::text').extract()']
```

and then loop through this array and pick each logic and execute it. Basically i have unlimited number of logic so i can't write all those in if/else block. what i want is something like this.

```
for logic in logicArr:  
            items=execute(logic)
            if items:
                self.write_items_to_file()
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for logic in logicArr:
    items=exec logic
    if items:
        self.write_items_to_file()
        break
```